# How to Remove Old PolylineOptions for add update new PolylineOptions

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I add the PolylineOption when the add new PolylineOption

OldPolylineOption not remove

```
GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();
Document doc = md.getDocument((new LatLng(lat, lng)),(new LatLng(lat2, lng2)),GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);
ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);
PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions();//.width(6).color(Color.RED);

for (int i = 0; i < directionPoint.size(); i++) {
  rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
}

Polyline polylin = this.mMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply clear the ArrayList, with directionPoint.clear();, empty the polylin with : polylin.remove(); then add the new directions.

Answer (score 1):

you have to clear the array of lat long an clear the GoogleMap object ..

```
directionPoint.clear();
mMap.clear();
```